# Omnipay extension - process_recurring returns error message

Tags: omnipay

We're running the 3.15 Omnipay extension with CiviCRM 5.46.2 under Wordpress.

Our hourly process_recurring job is returning an error as shown below and I was unable to find a reason. I set the debug to 1, but didn't see any additional log entries  --

```
Entity: Job Action: process_recurring
Summary
Finished execution of ProcessRecurring with result: Failure, Error message: invalid criteria for IN
Details

Parameters raw (from db settings): 
debug=1

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:2:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:5:"debug";s:1:"1";}

Full message: 
Finished execution of ProcessRecurring with result: Failure, Error message: invalid criteria for IN
```

Comment: We're getting the a similar message using version 3.18 of the Omnipay multiprocessor support extension with CiviCRM 5.50.2. The only apparent difference is the last parameter passed is now "0".

Answer (score 0):

Having exactly the same problem. Running Omnipay 3.15, Drupal 7.89 and CiviCRM 5.47.1. Temporarily disabled the process_recurring job. Not a long term fix!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/12053)